# Reference to const T initialized by value of type other than T

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, g++, clang++

For the following code:

```
struct A {
    explicit A(int) {}
};

const A& a(1);    // error on g++/clang++/vc++
const A& b = 1;   // error on g++/clang++/vc++
const A& c{1};    // ok on g++/clang++, error on vc++
const A& d = {1}; // error on g++/clang++/vc++
```

Which one(s) of the 4 initialization is(are) legal?

If we ignore vc++ first, it seems that the difference between direct-init and copy-init is not behaving consistently here.  If the third one is well-formed because it's direct-init, why does the first one which is also direct-init fail to compile?  What's the logic behind this?  Or it's just a bug for g++/clang++ and vc++ handles it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using *braced-init-lists* and the destination type of an initialization is a reference:

[dcl.init.list]/3 (from n3690)

> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` is not a reference type or its referenced type is
>     reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from
>     that element; if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to
>     convert the element to `T`, the program is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is copy-list-initialized or
>     direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for
>     the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary. [*Note:* As
>     usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the
>     reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. *— end note*]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

For the two examples `const A& c{1};` and `const A& d = {1};`, the second bullet of the quotation above applies. The first one direct-list-initializes a `const A`, the second one copy-list-initializes a `const A`. Copy-initialization selecting an `explicit` constructor is ill-formed, see [over.match.list]/1.

---

If you're not using braced-init-lists, there's no difference between copy-initialization and direct-initialization as far as I can tell. The last bullet of [dcl.init.ref]/5 applies in all cases:

> - Otherwise, a temporary of type “*cv1* `T1`” is created and initialized from the initializer expression
>     using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization (8.5). The reference is then bound to the
>     temporary.

Copy-initialization cannot select an `explicit` ctor, see [over.match.copy]/1 (it's not viable).

---

Conclusion:

```
const A& c{1};
```

is legal. The other are not, because they either use copy-initialization or copy-list-initialization and the only viable / selected ctor is `explicit`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quotes.  The quotes you presented here are much clearer than the corresponding parts in the formal 14882-2011 standard.  So to confirm, traditional initialization to reference doesn't respect the difference between direct-init and copy-init and always required an implicit conversion, while c++11 list initialization does treat direct-init and copy-init differently.  Correct?

Comment: @goodbyeera Yes. Note there are defects related to list-initialization and specifically related to initialization of references via braced-init-lists; for example [CWG DR 1288](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288). As g++ and clang++ will include many proposed resolutions in their `-std=c++11` modes, you can't rely on the official Standard to know what your compiler tries to do :/

Comment: @goodbyeera Oh, there's also [CWG DR 1494](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1494)

Comment: Great information!  I was indeed very confused when I read that the standard requires to create a prvalue temporary regardless of the initializer's type.  The 1288 bug track saves me.  Fortunately, it seems that major compilers are not following the standard for this particular issue.

Comment: Wow, #1494 seems to be direct answer to my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your struct can only be created by an explicit call to it's constructor. No implicit conversion is allowed.

A const reference must point to an existing object of that type on construction.

None of your lines create an object of type A by calling it's explicit constructor. So I don't see why any of those lines should properly initialize a const reference.